# Extremely slow performance in Control Panel on a VPS

Tags: performance

I am running a staging environment with Craft on a Dreamhost VPS (1 GB Ram, 30 GB SSD Storage). The backend is running incredibly slow. I noticed in the browser dev tools under network the following:

[image]

As you can see, the load time for "entries" is 7.5 seconds and index.php?=-admin… is 6s — these are really long load times.

I did a test on a separate domain, same server and all and I noticed when I first install Craft and once in the control panel, it was slow. After a bit of research, I added the code below to the "general.php" file in the config folder and instantly the issue is resolved for the test domain, but this solution did not work for the staging environment.

```
'*' => [
    'allowUpdates' => true,
],
```

It cannot be the VPS specs, it seems to me to be a configuration setting within Craft somewhere. I have other VPS accounts with same specs with live sites and not a problem at all.

Not sure if anyone has had similar experiences with Dreamhost or another hosting company with these issues…

Comment: Have you tried switching on the debug bar to see if that shows any particular actions or queries to be taking a long time? You can do this with the _Show the debug toolbar in the control panel_ and _Show the debug toolbar on the front end_ settings on your user account. It may also be worth comparing your `php.ini` and NGINX/Apache configurations to the servers where things run normally for you, just in case something funky is going on there.